# How to print multiple Employee details with below requirement which collection type can be used in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I want to store data as below format to any function of java collection  and print the output:-

```java
[
   { id->100, name->'praveen', mobile-9455104973 },
   { id->101, name->'Saurbh', mobile-7355078643 },
   { id->103, name->'Shivendr', mobile-123456789 } 
]
```

Output:

```
ID   Name       Mobile
100  Praveen    9455104973
101  Saurbh     735078643
102  Shivendra  123456789
```

Comment: Could you add Employee Classes, please ?

Comment: Please take as Emp as class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you create an employee class.

```
public class Employee {
private int id;
private String name;
private long phoneNumber;

/**
 * @param id
 * @param name
 * @param phoneNumber
 */
public Employee(int id, String name, long phoneNumber) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return id + "\t" + name + "\t" + phoneNumber + "\n";
}
}
```

After that you create a list of employees and initialize it with the employees you are interested in and print it.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(new Employee(100, "praveen", 9455104973L));
    employees.add(new Employee(101, "Saurbh", 7355078643L));
    employees.add(new Employee(103, "Shivendr", 123456789L));
    
    System.out.println("ID\tName\tMobile");
    
    for (Employee e: employees)
        System.out.println(e.toString());
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID  Name    Mobile
100 praveen 9455104973

101 Saurbh  7355078643

103 Shivendr    123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension to above with better formatting and using some new java versions features.

```
String format = "%1$-10s %2$-10s %3$-10s \n";
Consumer<Employee> employeeData = e -> System.out.format(format, e.getId(),                                      e.getName(), e.getMobile());
    System.out.format(format, "ID", "Name", "Mpbile");
    List.of(new Employee(100, "praveen", 9455104973L),
            new Employee(101, "Saurbh", 7355078643L),
            new Employee(103, "Shivendr", 123456789L)
            ).stream().forEach(employeeData);`
```